# How to change this code into looping or simple way?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i have 3 id and want to running 3 function.

```
function getNilai() {
        var rangeName = document.getElementById('inama').value;
        var nama = dataq =>{
        document.getElementById('nama').value = dataq
        }         
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nama).nama(rangeName);
        var ttl = dataq =>{
        document.getElementById('ttl').value = dataq
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ttl).ttl(rangeName);
        var kelas = dataq =>{
        document.getElementById('kelas').value = dataq
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(kelas).kelas(rangeName);
      }
```

i want to using this code in simple way.

Comment: In your situation, are you required to run `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nama).nama(rangeName);`, `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ttl).ttl(rangeName);`, and `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(kelas).kelas(rangeName);` with the asynchronous process? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not required to run `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(nama).nama(rangeName);`, `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ttl).ttl(rangeName);`, and `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(kelas).kelas(rangeName);` with the asynchronous process, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following script to your Google Apps Script side. This function is called from the Javascript side.

```js
const main = rangeName => [nama(rangeName), ttl(rangeName), kelas(rangeName)];
```

#### Javascript side:

Please modify your showing script as follows.

```js
function getNilai() {
  var rangeName = document.getElementById('inama').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(v =>
    ['nama', 'ttl', 'kelas'].forEach((e, i) => document.getElementById(e).value = v[i])
  ).main(rangeName);
}
```